# Mismatch in tag's Stats and Info page

Tags: bug, status-completed, statistics

The Info page for a tag shows how many upvotes I received for that tag at the bottom of the page.  Nice feature.  But the number doesn't match with what I see in the Stats page for the tag in the All Time list, it is consistently higher.  A sampling:

C# tag: info = 3764, stats = 3645
.NET tag: info = 2158, stats = 2101
C++ tag: info = 1027, stats = can't see but no badge

Etcetera, same pattern in other tags.  The mismatch is a bit too large to explain it with downvotes and deleted answers, but not really sure about that.  No biggie btw, I do like the Info page number better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its true, the tag info page displays the number of upvotes you got in a tag, the tag stats does a sum(Score) so the tag info page will almost always be higher.

I have a few options here:

1. Go with sum(Score) in both spots.
2. Go with sum(Upvotes) in both spots (too slow for stats so not going to happen)
3. Change nothing (improve the descriptions)

<strike>I'm not sure what to go with.</strike>

Changed it so we go with (1) everywhere, it should cut down on confusion.

Comment: You're going too fast for me Sam.  How is "Score" different from "Upvotes"?  Are you adding answer marks to "Score" in addition to upvotes?  That doesn't add up.

Comment: Score = Upvotes - Downvotes

Comment: Ouch, licking my wounds at the number of downvotes I must have gotten.  Hundreds?  Dozens, at most, I thought.  Kinda sure btw.  I can see perf as a problem, go ahead and improve the description.

Comment: I prefer score since it's faster and denormalized.

Comment: I counted 73 downvotes in my rep report.  Something is wrong.

Comment: At the very least you need to improve the description - it had me confused enough to post a bug report - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61877/is-there-a-problem-with-tag-badge-script-or-the-vote-total-on-the-tag-info-page (which I've subsequently voted to close)