# Is there a problem with tag badge script or the vote total on the tag info page?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Mismatch in tag’s Stats and Info page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61633/mismatch-in-tags-stats-and-info-page)

There's either a problem with the mechanism that counts the up-votes on tags or there's a problem with the script that awards the badges.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=.net&sort=info&pagesize=50 I've been:

> upvoted 410 times on non community-wiki answers with this tag.

[image: official up-votes]

However, I haven't yet been awarded the [.net] silver badge. It's been a few days since I hit 400 according to this page but I wanted to wait a while in case there was a delay.

However, if I check with the so-tag-votes Greasemonkey script I get a total of only 400 votes (which I have just hit today):

[image: Greasemonkey up-votes]

So if the official tally is to be believed then there is a problem with the badge script/stored procedure has it hasn't awarded me the badge despite being being 10 votes over the total required for a few (at least 3) days now.

However, if the Greasemonkey script is correct (The version I've got can be found [here](http://www.forman.free-online.co.uk/uploads/so-tag-votes.user.js.txt)) then the script hasn't run yet (which I can and do accept) but the code used to calculate the tally on the tag page is incorrect.

So which is it?

Comment: What about requesting a recalc to settle that possible dust?

Comment: @random - so you're saying that both could be wrong. Interesting. I'll see what answers (if any) I get and leave it 24 hours to give the script chance to run. I've only just hit 400 according to the Greasemonkey script so in that sense I was a bit premature posting this, but I wanted to do it while I remembered.

Comment: As far as i recall its upvotes only for the tags info page and upvotes minus downvotes in the tag stats... can't find the last question for it right now.

Comment: @Georg - If that's the case then there's no problem! If you can find the reference post it as an answer and I'll accept it & just be more patient.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61633/mismatch-in-tags-stats-and-info-page - voting to close.

Comment: Just noticed it now says "You have a total score of 400 on non community-wiki answers with this tag" so everything matches now. Just have to wait for the badge...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag info pages shows only upvotes while the tag stats show upvotes minus downvotes (and the GM script calculates those values AFAIR) - see e.g. [waffles answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61633/mismatch-in-tags-stats-and-info-page/61638#61638).

Adding to that that tag badges are awarded with a batch job there is no problem, just have a little patience :)

Comment: Thanks Georg. Answer accepted and I've voted to close my own question.